# What does the symbol % in '%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' mean?

Tags: sudo

What does the symbol % in the following statement mean:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Is it the same to write as:

```
sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adapted from [an answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/177253/what-are-the-percentage-signs-for-in-the-sudoers-file):

> A percent sign is used to indicate that the identifier that follows should be used as the name of a group instead of a user.

So here, `sudo` is the name of the group not the user `sudo`.